# How to add 1 month to datetimepicker when it's first day of the month?

Tags: c#

I am new to c# and I am using windows forms.

I have 2 `datetimepicker`, I sat `datetimepicker1` to first day of the month with customized time (`10:00:00`) as following  :

```
dateTimePicker1.Value = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month,1, 10,0,0);  //result : 2016/03/1 10:00:00
```

Now I want to set `datetimepicker2` to have the value of `datetimepicker1` but to add one month with this time `04:00:00`. i mean I want to set `datetimepicker2` with the current year and current month and first day of the month with `04:00:00` time but add one month to the current month.

Please help me how to do that. Thank you

Comment: Look at `DateTime.AddMonths`

Comment: What if the current month is December?  I assume you would want it to go to January of the next year right?  Also if I understand correctly, if I select December 13, 2015, you want the second one to go to: January 1, 2016?

Comment: `dateTimePicker2.Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.AddMonths(1);` at least for a start. This will not give you the first day or the the right time, but it's something to go off of.

Comment: @rbm . I already did , but it does not work inside new DateTime() it says can not convert datetime to int. so I used convert.toInt I ran the program then it throws an error "can not cast dateTime to int"  any idea?

Comment: @ CodingGorilla ,  it is all under button click . so if i click button: datetimepicker1 go to first day of the current month at 10:00:00 and datetimepicker2   goes to first day of next month at 04:00:00.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not

```
var a = new DateTime(2016,12,21, 10, 00, 00);
var aPlusMonth = a.AddMonths(1);
Console.WriteLine(a);
var nextMonth = new DateTime(aPlusMonth.Year, aPlusMonth.Month,1,04,00,00);
Console.WriteLine(nextMonth);
```

prints

```
21/12/2016 10:00:00
01/01/2017 04:00:00
```